# Rails js render partial after clearing previous template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have a rails app with a homepage linked to homeController.
Using javascript on a link click (put action), I would like to reset ("clean") my whole template, then render a completly new partial in my homepage.

So far i've got this :

Controller :

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    //classic home action
  end

  def physical
    respond_to do |format|               
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Link :

```
<%= link_to 'Retail Store', home_physical_path, remote: true %>
```

Js file named "_physical.js.erb" :

```
$('#empty-body').html("");
$('#empty-body').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'physical') %>");
```

View named "physical.html.erb" :

```
<div>html layout</div>
```

With this previous code, i have no errors, but my js seems to never be called cause the page doesn't update at all.
I've tried to add :

```
format.js { render partial: 'physical' }
```

On my physical method in my controller, but then when i call my method, my console return this & kill:

```
Segmentation fault
```

After few working around, I was able to "reset" my template after the click (page completly empty), but not to render my new partial in it.
The problem seems to come from the js trying to render the partial here :

```
$('#empty-body').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'physical') %>");
```

Which seems to cause the segmentation fault...

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should just rename your files: `physical.js.erb` and `_physical.html.erb`. Partials should start with `_`.

Comment: Thanks markets, you're the best !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to rename your files:

- `_physical.js.erb` => `physical.js.erb` (default rails views workflow without `_`)
- `physical.html.erb` => `_physical.html.erb` (partials with `_`)